# Multithreading in place of multiprocessing with celery

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, celery, distributed-computing

I am a little frustrated with [celery documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/index.html). I understand that the command

```
celery -A my-module worker -l INFO -n w1
```

starts a worker instance named `w1`. This means that the worker instance starts some default number of "**processes**" in the OS.

But can celery also start threads instead of processes? For example what does the following command do?

```
celery -A my-module worker --pool threads -l INFO -n w1
```

I tried reading through the documentation but could not find anything that would give an answer to the question "What does multi threading mean when it comes to celery? Can celery support multi threading in place of multi processing?"